# After a SQL query I don't know where the result comes from

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to update the database of a `Worpress` site. I managed to found the two tables on `phpMyAdmin` that are needed for the query: City Details (with city name and postcode) and distribution zone name (with provider and plan page id); tables are joined by distribution zone id.

After the user enters the arguments for the query, the response doesn't come from the database, seems to be another data base...
I don't understand the final result of this query. This results are the ones that I need to update.

```
    //enquire price
if(isset($_POST["postcode_suburb"])) {
$postcode_suburb = $_POST["postcode_suburb"];
$postcode=substr($postcode_suburb, 0, 4);
$suburb=substr($postcode_suburb, 5);
$query = 
"SELECT wp_8jhcgrrzks_city_detail.postcode,wp_8jhcgrrzks_city_detail.city_name,wp_8jhcgrrzks_distribution_zone.distribution_zone_name, wp_8jhcgrrzks_distribution_zone.plan_page_id FROM wp_8jhcgrrzks_distribution_zone 
INNER JOIN wp_8jhcgrrzks_city_detail ON wp_8jhcgrrzks_city_detail.distribution_zone_id = wp_8jhcgrrzks_distribution_zone.distribution_zone_id 
WHERE wp_8jhcgrrzks_city_detail.postcode='".$postcode."' AND wp_8jhcgrrzks_city_detail.city_name='".$suburb."'";
$page_id;
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch object array (THIS IS THE PART I DON'T UNDERSTAND */

    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $page_id = $obj->plan_page_id;
    }
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
  WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();

    global $helmets;

    $post_id = get_post($page_id);
    $content = $post_id->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
    echo do_shortcode($content);
```

Comment: This is not the right way how to run queries in WordPress. check this. http://www.stevendobbelaere.be/running-database-queries-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `wp_reset_query();` just before the code to reset the WordPress Query.

Use WordPress queries to get the results.

```
global $wpdb;

$result = $wpdb->get_results ($query);
```

You are getting the $page_id in a loop so if there are multiple results then it will only
get the content on the last Id.

You can try the above suggestion and let me know in case of any further help.

Thanks,